# C# Add additional attribute to nested object if it has one attribute at same level

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have one string and this is dynamic so it doesn't have static structure, so I converted it to dynamic object. But I have one issue and I don't have any idea how add additional attribute to object

```
string data="{\"message\":null,\"hasError\":false,\"errors\":[],\"data\":[{\"version\":\"1.1\",\"documents\":[{\"documentState\":\"Correct\",\"documentData\":{\"name\":\"PassportEEE\",\"type\":\"Document\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"Text\",\"suspiciousSymbols\":\"0000\",\"recognizedValue\":\"test\",\"value\":\"test\"}]},\"documentAsBase64\":\"\"}]}]}"
dynamic? data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonText);
```

now above you can see one nested object and here there is one attribute as **suspiciousSymbols**  here if I can find this object I want to add one more attribute at same level as **confidenceLevel** attribute

Coming object will be

```
{
  "message": null,
  "hasError": false,
  "errors": [],
  "data": [
    {
      "version": "1.1",
      "documents": [
        {
          "documentState": "Correct",
          "documentData": {
            "name": "PassportEEE",
            "type": "Document",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "test",
                "type": "Text",
                "suspiciousSymbols": "0000",
                "recognizedValue": "test",
                "value": "test"
              }
            ]
          },
          "documentAsBase64": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and expected object will be

```
{
  "message": null,
  "hasError": false,
  "errors": [],
  "data": [
    {
      "version": "1.1",
      "documents": [
        {
          "documentState": "Correct",
          "documentData": {
            "name": "PassportEEE",
            "type": "Document",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "test",
                "type": "Text",
                "suspiciousSymbols": "0000",
                "confidenceLevel": 100,
                "recognizedValue": "test",
                "value": "test"
              }
            ]
          },
          "documentAsBase64": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me about this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with just a dynamic "type" alone, all dynamic means is that type checking is skipped by the runtime. Luckily for you .NET made an object built to expand it's called `ExpandoObject`.

```
// Using .NET 6, C# 10, JSON.Net 13.0.3
string data = "{\"message\":null,\"hasError\":false,\"errors\":[],\"data\":[{\"version\":\"1.1\",\"documents\":[{\"documentState\":\"Correct\",\"documentData\":{\"name\":\"PassportEEE\",\"type\":\"Document\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"Text\",\"suspiciousSymbols\":\"0000\",\"recognizedValue\":\"test\",\"value\":\"test\"}]},\"documentAsBase64\":\"\"}]}]}";
dynamic x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>(data);

if(x.data[0]?.documents[0]?.documentData?.fields[0]?.suspiciousSymbols is not null){
    ((System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject)x.data[0]?.documents[0]?.documentData?.fields[0]).TryAdd("confidenceLevel", 100);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

---

Of course, keep in mind this is an example, you will probably need to modify this to reach your liking. `Newtonsoft` works out of the box like this `System.Text.Json` will take some more work; it does not do nested objects well like `Newtonsoft` does.